# How to run a C method from a tcl script?

Tags: c, tcl

I have a C method to add two numbers which looks like this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int add_two_numbers (int a , int b)
{    
    int sum;
    sum = a+b;
    return sum;
}
```

Now I want to call this c method from a tcl script.
How should I do it ?

Comment: To run a C function, you would normally compile a file containing the function into an executable format, passing in arguments if appropriate. From there, you can execute the binary file in TCL.

Comment: what is the command to be used in tcl to compile and execute the c method by passing the parameters ?

Comment: Do some research on "critcl" -- I've never had to use it but I understand it's a way to call C code from Tcl. "Compile on the fly" I think.

Comment: The other alternative is SWIG; for code this simple, it should be fine for generating the glue code required.

Comment: I heard about swig but didn't want to use it. I wanted to know if there was any way to write a tcl script that will act as a wrapper around my C function and call it with required arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You might try compiling your C code and making it a shared library. Then use the TCL "load" command to load it. There is some setup work you'll need. See the examples in the documentation for the TCL "load" command.